# How to declare two classes for element with scss

Tags: css, sass, styles

I have this scss code:

```
button.green{
  background-color: $green;
  .current {
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

I want to apply two classes to my button `<button class="green current"></button>` but my scss code just does not work. How would you fix that in a proper scss manner?

Also tried that with no luck:

```
button {
  .green{
    background-color: $green;
  }
  & .current {
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly correct, missing "&" in your nesting to connect button.green and .current.

The css output of your scss is:

```
button.green > .current
```

meaning, you style an element "current" within its parent "button.green".

Correct:

```
button.green{
  background-color: $green;
  &.current {
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
button.green.current
```

Comment: how would you debug the scss output?

Comment: what is the difference between `&.current` and `& .current` just placed the blank space at first then figure out that taking out the blank space makes a difference.

Comment: Debug? Watch at the written css :-)
Have a look here --> https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 0):

```
.green.current {
     background-color: $green;
     color: $white;
}
```

This will apply both class!!

Comment: how would you make sure it is works only for the `<button>`?

Comment: Incorrect. If both classes apply to the same element (which it does in this case), you would need to remove the space between `.green` and `.current`.